# How to send data as a form via HttpPost to server in Android?

Tags: android, xml, http, http-post

I am working on an android project in which i need to send two xml as parameters to server using post method(i.e. i want to send as form). I am tried to send data by using following code but its not working. No data in the remote database.

```
private void postFormData(List<DataItem> ti,String ex,String getExpensesXml)
{    
//Create a new Http Client 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); 
try
{ 
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sync","true"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tt",ti));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("te",ex)); 

    UrlEncodedFormEntity form; 
    form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");  
    httppost.setEntity(form); 

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
    String line = EntityUtils.toString(entity);    
    System.out.println(line);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I couldn't find what was the problem. It would be great if anyone manage to find the problem and suggest me the solution.

I have two more question?
Am i trying the correct code?
Is there any other way to send xml data to server via Form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "but its not working" is not helpful. What have you done to debug this issue? Are there any exceptions client side? Does your HttpServer see the incoming POST? Does your database have transaction handling? Did the insert fail due to integrity violation? You have to do better here.

Comment: Do you get a response from the server printed in your println()? Or maybe you're getting an exception?

Comment: 1.  Log the URL to make sure it's correct.  2.  Make sure you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in your manifest.  3.  Log your response.getStatusLine and make sure you're getting as far as the server request with a successful response.  4.  Log your exception

Comment: @Alex ya i am getting response from the server.. its normal html as response

Comment: @Anirudh No exceptions... i couldn't see the remote database it has control over the another person.. he saying he didn't received any data

Comment: @Rich ya i done all those.. i am getting html response from server but not stored in database

Comment: If you have something like 200 OK response from the server then ask the other guy to check server logs.
And you can send your POST request from some tool to eliminate your dependency on your client such as Fidler tool http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Thanks Alex. Actually i am getting 200 as response from server and i will let him to check the server logs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution , I used the following code to send the data as a from to server

```
URL siteUrl;
    try {
        siteUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        String content1 = ""; 

        Set getkey = param.keySet();
        Iterator keyIter = getkey.iterator();
        String content = "";
        for (int i = 0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
            Object key = keyIter.next();
            if (i != 0) {
                content += "&";
            }
            content += key + "=" + param.get(key);
            System.out.println("Content" + content);
        }

        System.out.println(content);
        out.writeBytes(content.trim());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
}
```

It may helpful for some one like me.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem. But Finally managed to Post data to Server. Your code is absolutely the way it should be except that you have to encode your `String` to `Base64` and then pass it to `NameValuePair`. At Server side you have to decode your `String` back from `Base64`. It will work. I can share code if you need.